# Cumulative subtraction from first row

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, math, matrix

I have one series and one DataFrame, all integers.

```
s = [10,
     10,
     10]

m = [[0,0,0,0,3,4,5],
     [0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
     [10,0,0,0,0,5,5]]
```

I want to return a matrix containing the cumulative differences to take the place of the existing number.

Output:

```
n = [[10,10,10,10,7,3,-2],
     [10,10,10,10,9,8,7],
     [0,0,0,0,0,-5,-10]]
```

Comment: Where is the dataframe?

Comment: m = dataframe / matrix

Comment: What you show us looks like Python lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculate the cumsum of data frame by row first and then subtract from the Series:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(s) 
df = pd.DataFrame(m)

-df.cumsum(1).sub(s, axis=0)

#    0   1   2   3  4  5   6
#0  10  10  10  10  7  3  -2
#1  10  10  10  10  9  8   7
#2   0   0   0   0  0 -5 -10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly compute a cumulative difference using `np.subtract.accumulate`:

```
# make a copy
>>> n = np.array(m)
# replace first column
>>> n[:, 0] = s - n[:, 0]
# subtract in-place                                                                                           
>>> np.subtract.accumulate(n, axis=1, out=n)                                                                        
array([[ 10,  10,  10,  10,   7,   3,  -2],                                                                         
       [ 10,  10,  10,  10,   9,   8,   7],                                                                         
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  -5, -10]])
```